# Using the 2nd conditional with present tenses

Tags: conditional-constructions

I know I ask a lot of questions on conditionals here.
It's probably because how they work interest me a lot.

Suppose someone says

"If I was a bacon company owner, I'd see to it that you **get** a lifetime supply of free bacon."

Is it grammatically correct, the construction?

Does it mean the same thing as, "...., i'd see to it that you **got** a lifetime supply of free bacon."

Comment: I'd make sure you had a lifetime supply....I'd make sure you have a lifetime supply. To my ear, the present (you have) sounds clumsy but the meaning is the same...he isn't a bacon tycoon and you don't have a lifetime supply of free bacon. But he would if he could. The present is better suited to "When I inherit the family bacon business, I'll make sure you have..."

Answer (score -1):

Both "get" and "got are fine.  The difference in *meaning* between the two is subtle and minimal, because you're talking about it from the point of view of a hypothetical situation:

"If I owned a bacon factory, I would make sure that you would receive a lifetime supply of bacon."

"If I owned a bacon factory, I would make sure to put you in a situation where you received a lifetime supply of bacon."

Either way, bacon. These are just two different ways to say more or less the same thing.